# What are the difference and use-cases for va_list, CVaListPointer, AnyObject ..., CVarArgType?

Tags: objective-c, swift, nspredicate, variadic-functions

**Question**

Can someone please explain the differences between these argument types? Furthermore, if possible please supply appropriate use-cases using code (it's worth a 1000 words).

**Nota bene**

Please let me know in the comments if there is any requirement for more information.

**Background**

I am attempting to understand any differences between the following constructs and understand the appropriate use-cases (with examples if there are any). I've searched SO, Google, et, al. (blogosphere) without finding a satisfactory answer.

In writing a data store object, I came across the following initializers for an NSPredicate:

[image: NSPredicate-initializers]

The Swift header file (1.2) notes:

[image: CVaListPointer]

A blog comment indicates the following usage of va_list in Objective-C

```
+ (void) log:(NSString *) format arguments:(va_list) argList
{
    [self logString: [NSString stringWithFormat: format arguments:
argList]];
}

+ (void) log:(NSString *) format, ...
{
    va_list argList;
    va_start(argList, format);
    {
  [self log: format arguments: argList];
    }
    va_end(argList);
}
```

CVarArgType is a protocol and can be used as follows according to the Swift header file.

[image: CVarArgType]

In my custom class I have the following use-case:

```
   /*  Finds an array of entity in the MOC if any exists using an optional
    *   predicate with an array of arguments
    *
    *   Usage:
    *   eg. var items = CustomEntity.findInStore(dbStore, predicate:
    *   NSPredicate(format: "(attributeName IN %@)", argumentArray:
    *   ["value1","value2","value3"])) as? [CustomEntity]
    */
```

**EDIT:**

Readers please note that the argumentArray parameter was incorrectly used as described in my custom class. To correctly use this initializer, note the following from Apple's documentation:

[image: argumentArray-doc]

Which leads me to this usage:

```
NSPredicate(format: "(%K != %@ AND %K = %@)", argumentArray: ["key1","value1","key2","value2"])
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

`va_list` is a C type used for variable argument functions. You'll see this as a parameter in Objective-C code.

`CVaListPointer` is the swift equivalent of a `va_list`--wherever you see a function in Objective-C that takes `va_list` as an argument, you'll pass in a `CVaListPointer` in Swift.

```
objective-c: (NSPredicate *)predicateWithFormat:(NSString *)format arguments:(va_list)argList
swift: init(format format: String, arguments argList: CVaListPointer) -> NSPredicate
```

`CVarArgType` is a protocol that defines what kind of types can be included in a `CVaListPointer`, this includes all the primitives (`Int`, `Float`, `UInt`, etc) as well as `COpaquePointer`

The utility function `withVaList` takes a Swift array and transforms it into a `CValListPointer`, which is then passed to a callback. Note that the array passed in must contain only `CVarArgType` variables:

```
var format = "%@ != %@"
var args: [CVarArgType] = ["abc", "def"]

var s = withVaList(args) { (pointer: CVaListPointer) -> NSPredicate in
    return NSPredicate(format: format, arguments: pointer)
}
```

Swift also defines its own varadic parameter `T...`, which must be the last parameter in a function, it is passed into the function as `[T]` and is used like so.

```
var arg1: String = "abc"
var arg2: String = "def"
NSPredicate(format: format, arg1, arg2)
```

Use Swift's built in varadic parameters `T...` wherever possible. `CValListPointer` should only be used when you need to interface with Objective C and C APIs that accept `va_list` arguments.