# Can't pass DateInRegion to NSPredicate(format: …)

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nspredicate

I have a code:

```
let dateInFormat = selectedDate.toString()

let predicate = NSPredicate.init(format: "date = %@",arguments:selectedDate )
```

But it doesn't work and I tried to convert it into different type using in format - operator "as" string or `dateInRegion` or something but all the same.
Any help appreciated.

Comment: did you read an error?

Comment: Yes, and it' s like - "Can't convert value of  type "DateInRegion" to expected argument type "CVaListPointer" "

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are the difference and use-cases for va\_list, CVaListPointer, AnyObject ..., CVarArgType?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28639154/what-are-the-difference-and-use-cases-for-va-list-cvalistpointer-anyobject)

Comment: Note that you could use https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nspredicate/1587997-predicatewithformat?language=objc which is "simpler", especially in your case.